# How to avoid "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present ... " error with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I'm building a CSS parser based on JS and what it does it gets every script referenced in the  of the page, tries to get all of them with AJAX request, and parses them for specific rules.

The problem is when my js script bumps into something like:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The script fails and it is stopped from being executed further with a console message in Chrome

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&text&_=1412330695993. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydoma.in' is therefore not allowed access.

I understand that this is Chrome specific security settings that can be tuned up, but what I want is to prevent the script from being terminated every time it bumps into something unreachable like this.

Please feel free to ask for any clarification!

Comment: There is a few ways around. But why not save a copy of the file on your server and use it ?

Comment: Might be a solution, but I'm building a standalone js library that's supposed to work with no web service at the back.

Comment: So anyway you cant link to a file that is not with your files...

Comment: If there is no webservice the link to google api wont work

Comment: I don't want to link them if they are unlinkable or inaccessible. I want to avoid the script from being terminated every time it bumps into unlinkable stylesheet. The main question is how to protect the script from that.

Comment: It is not Chrome specific by the way - any half-decent browser will have CORS security measures built in and enabled. In any case it seems to me that when you attempt to fetch an url which has a different host/origin than where the script came from, you don't want to fetch it.

Comment: @Gimby hey thanks! I thought of that, but I hope maybe there's more merciful solution? Or the browser won't get me request another host anyways?

Comment: "A more merciful solution" has no meaning to me. If you're asking if it is possible to circumvent this security measure - I hope not, it exists for good reasons.

Comment: @Gimby Oh god, no! No one wants to circumvent anything. The question is how to forecast this possible security fails. Silly speaking: `if ( stylesheet == "restricted" ) { don't ask for this stylesheet; } else { doTheRoutines(); }`. Because now just asking for the stylesheet causes the WHOLE script to fail.

Answer (score -2):

Simply Add data-noprefix to the linker like

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' data-noprefix>
```

Comment: This does absolutely nothing on my side. What is that attribute supposed to do? Can you tell me why it should work? Maybe I'm doing it terribly wrong again :\